# How to make Sublime SVN plugin keeps locks on commit

Tags: svn, plugins, sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I'm using Sublime Text 3 with wbond Sublime SVN plugin, but any time i commit a file, i lose the lock.
Is there any option to make the plugin keeps the locks on files?

Comment: Looking into https://wbond.net/sublime_packages/svn/settings there is apparently no such thing. You could request that feature.